# How to get top x values from a list of a sum ( 3 tables ) - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the title but I didn't know what can I put in it :(.

I have 3 tables : `team` , `nation` and `results`.

Table `team` contains -> `id`, `name`, `id_nation`

Table `nation` contains -> `id`, `name`

Table `results` contains -> `id`, `id_team`, `points`

My problem is : I want to display the list of points by nations BUT, if there are 7 teams from a same nation, I have to "get" only the top 5 scores of this teams to make the total score of this nation.

Example, I have 7 teams ( team 1 , team 2 , team 3, ... team 7 ) from Spain who has id_nation like the id of the Spain nation. 
For each teams the sum of the total points from `results` table are like that :

```
Team 1 => 7 points
Team 2 => 9 points
Team 3 => 5 points
Team 4 => 5 points
Team 5 => 1 point
Team 6 => 10 points
Team 7 => 9 points
```

I remember to you that all these 7 teams are from Spain. So, normally, the total of Spain points must be -> ( 7 + 9 + 5 + 5 + 1 + 10 + 9 ) = 46 points.
BUT, me, like I said, I want only the top 5 teams by country. So, I want, for Spain in this example, a total of ( 10 + 9 + 9 + 7 + 5 ) = 40 points ans not 46 ( for the Spain team ).

I need your help because I don't know how to have this result in SQL ( MySQL ).
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: I'm using MySQL `5.7.23`

Comment: Can you upgrade your MySQL to 8.0+ ? That would make the answer to this problem very trivial..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pain.  Basically, you need variables to enumerate the rows and then filtering and aggregation:

```
select id_nation, sum(points)
from (select r.*,
             (@rn := if(@n = r.id_nation, @rn + 1,
                        if(@n := r.id_nation, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select r.*, t.id_nation
            from results r join
                 teams t
                 on r.team_id = t.id 
            order by t.id_nation, r.points desc
           ) r cross join
           (select @n := -1, @rn := 0) params
    ) r
where rn <= 5
group by id_nation;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample to make it on `mysql 5.7.23`,

The better way is using a window function, but unfortunately, it only supports on `mysql 8.0` or higher than it.

So you can try to declare a variable. the make row number then filter you want to `SUM` top of row.

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Result(
  points int
);

INSERT INTO Result VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO Result VALUES (9);
INSERT INTO Result VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO Result VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO Result VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO Result VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO Result VALUES (9);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUM(points)
FROM (
  SELECT t.points,(@rn := @rn + 1) rn
  FROM result t CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0 rn) v
  ORDER BY points DESC
) t
where rn <= 5
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b671ca/26/0)**:

```
| SUM(points) |
|-------------|
|          40 |
```

Comment: I will try to impletent it with my 3 tables